# Object has no method 'on' (EventEmitter in node)

Tags: node.js

My example :

```
var Common= {

    http: require("http"),
    url : require("url"),
    fs : require("fs"),
    util : require("util"),
    event : require("events")
}

var someobj ={name:'sasha'}
Common.util.inherits(someobj,Common.event.EventEmitter)
someobj.on('onparse',function(data){
    console.log(data + this.name);
});

someobj.emit('onparse','super log from');
```

Then in console error : 
**Object has no method on**

Help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor), the `inherits` method expects parameters of a constructor and a super constructor. You have supplied an object and a super constructor.

Note that the following is untested:

```
var Common= {
    http: require("http"),
    url : require("url"),
    fs : require("fs"),
    util : require("util"),
    event : require("events")
}

// Create a constructor function for the object
var SomeClass = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    Common.event.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

// Inherit the EventEmitter prototype
Common.util.inherits(SomeClass, Common.event.EventEmitter);

// Create the new object
var someobj = new SomeClass('Sasha')
someobj.on('onparse', function(data){
    console.log(data + this.name);
});

someobj.emit('onparse', 'super log from');
```